# Python os.path.exists fails with relative path with multiple "..", but works with absolute path

Tags: python, path

I am doing a simple `os.path.exists()` call but it's failing for a relative path with multiple `..` while it succeeds with the absolute path. I've tested and found that the path is too long with the relative path. If I take off characters (`extra` in the example below) of the filename it works.

The examples below aren't exactly the length of failures, just for examples of the issue I'm facing.

```
# relative path - too long
os.path.exists(r'..\..\..\..\folder1\folder2\folder3\folder4\myfilename_extra.txt')  # fails
# removed `extra` at end of filename
os.path.exists(r'..\..\..\..\folder1\folder2\folder3\folder4\myfilename.txt')  # succeeds
# absolute path
os.path.exists(r'C:\Users\alex\folder1\folder2\folder3\folder4\myfilename.txt')  # succeeds
```

Could someone explain why the multiple uses of `..` is causing the path to be too long and if there's a workaround. I can't use the absolute path either.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by adding `os.path.abspath` in front of each relative path. I'm assuming each `..` was being evaluated as a whole path.

`os.path.exists(os.path.abspath(r'..\..\..\..\folder1\folder2\folder3\folder4\myfilename_extra.txt'))  # now succeeds`